# Use token from parent entity

Tags: tokens, 10, entity

In a drupal 10 site I have a content type called **article** with an entity reference field on it called "Related nodes". Those related nodes are of type **page**. On the page content type there is a wysiwy field with tokens formatting enabled.

How can I access tokens of the parent entity of type article within the wysiwyg field on node of type page that is referenced in the "Related nodes" field?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the entity reference fields by using the entity keyword in the token, assuming your field is called `related_nodes` it would be `[node:field_related_nodes:entity]`

You should be able to access any field on the related node by appending the field name, e.g. `[node:field_related_nodes:entity:field_name]`

Comment: I interpreted the question as needing to access the reverse relationship. This is good for parent -> child, but won't be useful for child -> parent

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Colin Shipton but it is indeed like Clive says. I need the other way around...